# What type of PHP data type do I use?

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables

I've been staring at google, stack, and other sites for 4 days trying to get my head around this, so I appreciate any help you can offer... I'm a n00b, so apologies if I misuse any terms.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to build a band website just for practice. I want to create a block of code that stores multiple pieces of information about a song, then use that data in a music player. Each song will have its own player that will show the title of the song, a piece of art for the song, and allow you to play the song itself.

To keep the site loading time down, and to avoid repetitive code, I'd like to use a loop to make it so I have one chunk of code for the player(s), then create a separate iteration of the player for each song.

I think I can handle the loop aspect, but I can't figure out which data type to use for storing multiple pieces of info about the song. **Would this be an array, a function, something else?**

I'm not looking for someone to code this for me, I just want to know what direction head in.

Here's a rough sketch of what I mean, without proper syntax obviously:

```
$song(crashing) {  
  $songTitle = "Crashing";  
  $songPath = "crashingSong.php";  
  $songArtwork = "crashingArt.php";  
}

$song(Juliana) {  
  $songTitle = "Juliana";  
  $songPath = "julianaSong.php";  
  $songArtwork = "julianaArtwork.php";  
}

$player {
  echo "<div class=\"titleHead\">" . $songTitle . "</div>";
  echo "<div class=\"link\">" . $songPath . "</div>";
  echo "<div class=\"artwork\">" . $songArtwork . "</div>";
}
```

Then I would have a loop that would iterate the player for each song.

Help?

Comment: use a class and an array of instances of that class.

Comment: Agree, just dont forget to make a "Song class" manager (the one wich hydrate and store in the array the songs from Database) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store this info several ways. The first being a muli dimensional array, each song can have an element in an array, then contain a sub-array with the song data.

```
<?php

    //Store songs as multidemensional array
    $songs = array(
        'crashing' => array(
            'songTitle' => 'Crashing',
            'songPath' => 'crashingSong.php',
            'songArtwork' => "crashingArt.php"
        ),
        'Juliana' =>  array(
            'songTitle' => 'Juliana',
            'songPath' => 'julianaSong.php',
            'songArtwork' => "julianaArtwork.php"
        )
    );

    //Now iterate through each song
    foreach($songs as $title => $data) {

        echo "<div class=\"titleHead\">" . $data['songTitle'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"link\">" .  $data['songPath'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"artwork\">" . $data['songArtwork'] . "</div>";

    }   

?>
```

The second way would be to create a class with the songs and add some methods to help save and retrieve those songs.

```
<?php

class Songs {

    private $songs = array();

    // method declaration
    public function addSong($songTitle, $songPath, $songArtwork) {

        $this->songs[] = array(
            'songTitle' => $songTitle,
            'songPath' => $songPath,
            'songArtwork' => $songArtwork
        );

    }

    public function getSongs() {
        return $this->songs;
    }

}


//Initilaize songs class
$songRef = new Songs();

//Add SOngs
$songRef->addSong('Crashing', 'crashingSong.php', 'crashingArt.php');
$songRef->addSong('Juliana', 'julianaSong.php', 'julianaArtwork.php');

$songs = $songRef->getSongs();

//Now iterate through each song
foreach($songs as $key => $data) {

    echo "<div class=\"titleHead\">" . $data['songTitle'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"link\">" .  $data['songPath'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"artwork\">" . $data['songArtwork'] . "</div>";

}

?>
```

Comment: `Songs::$songs` shouldn't be public.

Comment: @Rangad Just fixed that, thank you.

Comment: Your method worked perfectly, @battletoilet. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem! If you feel my answer was correct, please mark as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

An associative array of arrays will do the job.

Something like:

```
$songs = array(
   'crashing' => array('Title' => "Crashing",  
                       'Path' => "crashingSong.php",  
                       'Artwork' => "crashingArt.php"
                  ), //<repeat for more songs>
    );
```

Then you can loop through `$songs`. And you would access the title like `$songs['crashing']['Title']`.

However, this is a perfect time to leverage object oriented programing. You could have a song class with attributes like title, path, etc and a method called `renderPlayer()`. This is a little involved to handle in an SE answer, but you can Google around for tons of information on OOP PHP.

Actually Joe's answer is a great start at a song class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best defining a class to hold your information. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

You could store it in an array and just always have index 0 be the song title, etc.

You could also store it in an associative array where the indexes are strings instead of integers. Then is could be `$song['songTitle']`

The collection of bands could be stored the same way, jus nested.

Answer (score 0):

If the use case is as simple as what is described you could just use an array:

```
$songInfo = array( 
      'Crashing' => array('Title' => 'Crashing', 'Path' => "crashingSong.php", 'Artwork' => 'crashingArt.php')  
);
```

And then you can access those fields by e.g.:

```
$songInfo['Crashing']['Path']
```

If you intend to do anything more complicated, you should probably create a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all that information in what's called a class.

```
<?php 

class Song {
  private $Title;
  private $path;
  private $Artwork;
}

function Display(){
  echo "<div class=\"titleHead\">" . $this->DisplayTitle(). "</div>
        <div class=\"link\">" . $this->DisplayPath(). "</div>
        <div class=\"artwork\">" .$this->DisplayArtWork() . "</div>
       ";

function DisplayTitle() {
  echo $this->Title;
}

function DisplayPath(){
  echo $this->Path
}

function DisplayArtWork(){
  echo $this->Artwork
}

?>
```

A class is a "re-useable".

This is a sample class with some functions built in so you can see how they can be leveraged.

Comment: `var $Title`? PHP5 was introduced over 10 years ago. Also: `$this->Path` won't work, as your functions are not part of any class definition. Methods and functions don't `echo`, they `return`. And one last thing: _please_ check [the coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org), and apply them

Comment: It's a simple adaption to OPS question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300942/is-it-bad-practice-to-echo-out-functions-in-php

Comment: But it's ***broken code***, and it contains all sorts of bad practices (not specifying access modifier, using the 10-year-old, PHP-4 style `var` keyword, methods containing `echo`...). It's just bad code. I'm not trying to be mean here, just pointing out that this is a bad answer, IMO, for the reasons I mention. I commented, because this was the highest scoring answer when I saw it, and to give you the opportunity to _edit_ it. I didn't down-vote even... Mind you: care to explain why you -1 my answer?

Comment: You were correct that I shouldn't use var. I've fixed that. Why do you assume I -1 your answer?

Comment: 1 => your code is still broken (the functions are not methods, and they still echo instead of return). 2 => I happened to see your rep go down by 3 points, at around the time I got a -1, which lead me to believe you got a -1 on your answer (-2 rep), and down-voted yourself....

Comment: Functions can echo all they want. Read the link I posted about whether or not it's bad practice. I don't down vote good answers! Especially, people more knowledgeable then me on the subject.

Comment: But you use the return value of a function that returns nothing but echoes. That might work, if all functions are called in the right order, but it's a huge bug risk if other callers use that code. And your code would still fatal (and notice + warn on hhvm) if you run it. Using echo in functions that are not concerned with rendering data `display` in your answer makes them unusable in other contexts. You are limiting the reusability of your code without any benefit.

Comment: Read the first comment below the question: echo is considered bad practice. If you want to, check any of my answers on code review, where I explain why this is...

Answer (score 0):

You can use array for save your data (or a file .xml, .json).
For interact you can try (simple example, sorry):

```
$music = array(
    'songTitle'   => "Crashing",   
    'songPath'    => "crashingSong.php", 
    'songArtwork' => "crashingArt.php"
);

foreach( $music as $key => $value ){
    echo $key . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you'll only really need an associative array: a single variable, grouping some data together, with easy to remember/read/understand names:

```
$song = array(
    'artist' => 'Foo',
    'Title'  => 'Bar',
    'Album'  => 'Foobar',
);//and so on
```

Pretty soon, though, you'll find that programming by array is not the best way to create maintainable code. Not by a long shot. So what you'd probably want to do is create a class:

```
class Song
{
    protected $artist = null;
    protected $title = null;
    protected $album = null;
    public function setArtist($artist)
    {
        $this->artist = $artist;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getArtist()
    {
        return $this->artist;
    }
    //add getters and setters for other properties here
}
```

To avoid having to write:

```
$song = new Song();
$song->setArtist('foo')
    ->setTitle('bar');//and so on
```

all of the time, you'll want to add a constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $data)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->{'set'.ucfirst($key)}($value);//<-- of course, check if method exists first
    }
}
```

As an added bones, you can create classes that represent an album (containing an array of songs), or an `Artist` class, that in turn contains an array of songs, and an array of albums. That way, your objects can be grouped together easily.

Once you've done that, it's a simple matter of coupling those Model classes to a relational database schema (where an Album record references an artist record (foreign keys)), and each song references an album, so all the data is nicely linked together.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in about 10mins so its not perfect sure, but i Hope you know read UML (i obviously didn't made it in pure UML but that's a starting base) :)

[image: UML for Song and SongManager Classes]

PS : $_DMB is a variable where you have to stock your database manager (pdo or a wrapper)

Comment: for sure in the setters functions declaration you have to add the $data var or you will set nothing :D